# I want to re-name the button and disable it at the same time

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to rename the part were it says "Open Space and disable the button all when it is clicked.

```
from tkinter import *

board = Tk()

board.geometry("400x500")
board.title("Board")

b = Button(board, text="Open Space")
b.grid(row=0, column = 1)

c = Button(board, text="Open Space")
c.grid(row=0, column = 2)

d = Button(board, text="Open Space")
d.grid(row=1, column = 0)

e = Button(board, text="Open Space")
e.grid(row=1, column = 1)

f = Button(board, text="Open Space")
f.grid(row=1, column = 2)

g = Button(board, text="Open Space")
g.grid(row=2, column = 0)

h = Button(board, text="Open Space")
h.grid(row=2, column = 1)
i = Button(board, text="Open Space")
i.grid(row=2, column = 2)

board.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you read any documentation or did any searching for examples?

Comment: @BryanOakley You seem to know Tkinter, so you can help me! I was planning to answer this question, but my answer was more complicated than expected. While the callback is supposed to act on the button itself, is it possible to write stuff like `b = Button(command=b.stuff)`, or `b = Button(command=lambda : stuff(b))`? Otherwise, the only solution I see is to write a class inheriting from `Button` and implementing a custom callback... Which is IMO the best way to achieve this in real life, but it's far from easy... Have you any thoughts about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you can assign function to `Button` using

```
Button(..., command=function_name)
```

But you need access to button so you have to first create button and later assing function with argument - button instance - and this function will change text and disable button.

```
b['command'] = lambda:change(b)

# or 

b.config(command=lambda:change(b))
```

---

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- function ---

def change(widget):
    widget.config(text='o', state='disabled')
    #widget['text'] = 'o'
    #widget['state'] = 'disabled'

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

a = tk.Button(root, text="Open Space")
a['command'] = lambda:change(a)
a.pack()

b = tk.Button(root, text="Open Space")
b.config(command=lambda:change(b))
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

Maybe you don't need disabled button but you need to remove assigned function:

```
def change(widget):
    widget.config(text='o', command=None)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this when the button is cliked?

Comment: I don't understand your question. It changes text and disable button when you click button ?

Comment: def changeName():
    a = Button(board, text ="o", state = "disabled") # is says the "a" variable is local  This is the code when I tried to assign the command to a button:

Comment: b = Button(board, text="Open Space", command= changeName())
b.grid(row=0, column = 1)

Comment: that's true `a` is local variable because you create it inside function. But I don't know why you create new Button if you can change text in existing button.

Comment: `command=` expects function name - it means without `()` and arguments. And this is why I use `lambda` to assign function without arguments but inside this function use `change(b)` with argument.

Comment: When I click the button, I want the label to display "o" instead of "Open Space" and also disabled. Sorry if i was to specific enough.

Comment: But my example does it. You have to only change text `Close Space` to `o` .

Comment: Do you mean manually changing the string "Open Space" to "o"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the Button widget simply write the changes want to do:

```
btnname.configure(state=tk.DISABLED, text='New Text', command=newcommand)
```

for your case to change the button b:

```
board.b.configure(state=tk.DISABLED, text='New Text', command=newcommand)
```

You disable a tk.Button with state=tk.DISABLED and you enable it with state=tk.NORMAL. If you don't want to change the command don't include it.

For a ttk.Button the state values are state='disabled' to disable it and state='!disabled' to enable it again